# Access a cgi Script Via a JavaScript

Tags: javascript, perl, cgi

I am trying to make a link where when it is clicked, it goes to the site it is supposed to, but it also runs a cgi script.  I have found different examples, but I still don't fully understand it.

In essence, I have two questions:

1. Where can I host the script so I can access it?
2. How do I access it?

Comment: And I don't know if the tags I chose are correct....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where can I host the script so I can access it?

If you want to access it from JavaScript then it has to be on the same origin (i.e. hostname and port) as the page the JavaScript is running in.

> How do I access it?

You can either forget JavaScript, have a regular link and then have the CGI perform a 302 redirect, or you can use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Beware of timing issues. It is possible for the browser to go to the next URL before it gets around to making the Ajax request. A redirect would probably be a better approach.

Comment: Incidentally, if you need to have the javascript get something from another domain (hostname and port), and you control the server, you can use cross origin resource sharing. Read this: http://enable-cors.org/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function callYourCGI(){
    var i = new Image();
    i.src = "your-cgi-url?name=value&name2=value2";
}
</script>
<a href="the-next-document.html" onclick="callYourCGI()">
```

The Image object is part of the HTML DOM. It allows you to manipulate images in an HTML page. Read about it here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/image.shtml

The script is creating an image object and then assigning the URL of your CGI script to the SRC attribute. This makes the browser perform a get request for the content of the URL. In this case, you aren't going to display the image object, so the content returned by your CGI script need not be a real image. If can be, if you want, though. Either way, the side-effect is that your CGI script is called, with some parameters if desired. An advantage of this method is that it does not violate the same origin policy, since images are allowed to be loaded from anywhere.

Comment: Thank you, but I am still not sure what this says...  Like, what is the "Image", and what does the i.src line mean?

Comment: And what is the link thingy?  Remember, I am a n00b at this.

Comment: @CodeAdmiral — In all seriousness, if your JavaScript skills are at that level then [you should learn the basics](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#JavaScript_core_skills) before trying to solve specific problems with JS.